# AngularJS $http request not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJS and I'm trying to work with Angular dependency injections which involve the use of $http service. I have a .json file in the same directory as my html file and I am referring to that file in my controller. However, for some reason, the view does not change to reveal my data. What am I doing wrong? I get an error alert every time, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="family" ng-controller="famctrl">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Search: <input ng-model="query">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10"><br>
            Sort by:
            <select ng-model="order">
                <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
                <option value="age">Age</option>
            </select>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="sword in swords | filter:query| orderBy:order"><span>{{sword.name}}</span>
                    <p>{{sword.quanity}}</p>
                    <p>{{sword.price}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <p>Total number of swords: {{swords.length}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**family.js**

```
    var family = angular.module('family', []);

family.controller('famctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('records.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.swords=data;
    }).
    error(function(data){
        alert('error');
    });
    $scope.order="name";
});
```

records.json has the following format:

```
[
    {
        "name": "...",
        "quantity": "...",
        "price": "..."
    },...
]
```

Comment: and what is the error do you get ?

Comment: do a `console.log(data)` inside error handler and see what is wrong in your browser console.

Comment: This is the error I get:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/razboinic/Desktop/Angular/records.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You cannot access a local file system path via ajax. It should be a relative/absolute web url.

Comment: Gotcha. So what would be the correct way to do this get request? I tried creating a web server using python, and it does give me a 200 back, but for some reason, it doesn't update the view at all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this!

```
family.controller('famctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('records.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.swords=data;
    }).
    error(function(data){
        alert('error');
    });
    $scope.order="name";
}]);
```

Comment: When answering questions please provide explanation so that it can be more easily understood by other users of the site.

Comment: iSZ, I tried that and it still didn't change anything.

Comment: Tristan, what sort of explanation do you need? I tried my best to be as clear as possible, but if I'm missing something, lemme know

Comment: I think user3196429 probably has the correct answer. You may need to setup a local web server.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thanks a ton guys and thank you, user3196429, for the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

You must define like that:
'$scope', '$http' are load controller scope and http

```
family.controller('famctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('records.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.swords=data;
}).
error(function(data){
    alert('error');
});
$scope.order="name";
```

}]);